# How can I make Lamp Web Server Stack discoverable to others devices in LAN?

Tags: server, apache2, ip, wordpress

I've followed official Canonical Community [tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#1-overview) about setup basic Lamp Web Server stack to host WordPress sites (For local development). I tweaked it so it could work well with files permissions. It works fine on local machine, but I also need to test my websites on mobile devices too...

> [image]

I don't have domain yet, I'm using IP Address instead (For testing purposes). How can I configure Apache Web Server to be discoverable? I tried to look in many communities for help, I'm unable to find suitable one.

Comment: You have to use IP of the server on Android device. Something like `http://192.168.1.123` .

Comment: Thanks! Now I can access (Apache) website through mobile, but I can't reach WordPress because my browser says: net::eer_connection_refused

Comment: To this point I don't know if it's my ISP (Again) blocking my IP Address...

Comment: You are talking about LAN, it is not controlled by ISP. You have to read more about Local Area Networking technologies, hosts and IP addresses elsewhere.

Comment: How so? My LAN is connected to internet, WordPress needs Internet Access to work.

Comment: For local testing you need local IP. To publish your blog to Internet you need more measures like DynDNS or so.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to adjust the firewall on the system running Apache to allow connections over port 80. This is how you can do it:

1. Open Terminal or connect via SSH
2. List the `ufw` profiles:

   ```
   sudo ufw app list
   ```

   You should see something like this:

   ```
   Available applications:
     Apache
     Apache Full
     Apache Secure
     OpenSSH
   ```
3. Allow traffic to Apache over Port 80:

   ```
   sudo ufw allow 'Apache'
   ```
4. Check that other machines on the local network can access the machine.

This should be all you need to do so long as you are running a mostly stock Apache configuration.

Comment: I did that many times, I'm using default loopback interface (127.0.0.1) BTW and I don't know for sure if that may be contributing. I tried to map my dynamic IP Address given by ISP with WordPress base site as URL earlier (in /etc/hosts file), but it still wasn't working.